# How to have one row multiple columns instead of multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, conditional-aggregation

I have the following data:

[image]

In SQL Server How can I have group by `weekdate` so I have only one row for each `weekdate`, example for the `weekdate` **2015-11-14**:

[image]

> Any clue?

Answer (score 4):

Use conditional aggregation.

```
select cast(weekdate as date), 
sum(case when permittype = 0 then total else 0 end) as permittype0,
sum(case when permittype = 1 then total else 0 end) as permittype1
from tablename
group by cast(weekdate as date)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do this using conditional aggregation:

```
select weekdate,
       sum(case when permittype = 0 then total else 0 end) as permitttype0,
       sum(case when permittype = 1 then total else 0 end) as permitttype1
from followingdata t
group by weekdate
order by weekdate;
```

You can also use `pivot` syntax, if you prefer.